# Grails app run not successful due to javalaunchhelper

Tags: grails, java-8, osx-yosemite

I have a very basic grails app that is complete but I can not run it. I see the following message in the console. It is so apparently because **I have two versions of jdk installed on my mac but I have only one set up to use in my profile/environment**.

```
MacBook-Pro:AutoMart myMac$ grails run-app
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun
objc[4655]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080
> Building 83% > :bootRun
```

The following is what I see on the browser.
[image: grails run-app (browser)]

Do I have to uninstall one of the JDKs? Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the page not found error and the JDK error message are related to each other.

Just make sure that your "Automart" application has a defined homepage. In your conf/URLMapping.groovy yoiu should have

```
 "/" {
   controller = "homepage"
   action = "index"
}
```

Comment: The URLMapping.groovy file is in the controller folder. I did change with what you have suggested in the answer but nothing. The browser now even says something about error: **An error has occurred
Exception:
Message: No message available
Path: /AutoMart/**